# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: asp.net, casting, datatable

I am getting this error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TransTripLeg]'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

and I can't seem to figure out how to resolve it. The error occurs at `DataTable dtTable =`  in the code below.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["EditMode"]))
{
    DataTable dtUpdate = (DataTable)Session["TripRecords"];
    DataRow[] customerRow = dtUpdate.Select("LegID = '" + sLegID.ToString() + "'");
```

I think I am casting it to type DataTable, but then I still get the error.

Comment: As the error _clearly_ states, it isn't a DataTable.

Comment: Session["TripRecords"] is of type List<TransTripLeg>. I would guess "(DataTable)Session["TripRecords"];" would be casting it to type DataTable.

Comment: You can't simple cast everything to everything - types have to have something in common.

Comment: @Csharp: Casting cannot convert an object to an unrelated type.  Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `Session["TripRecords"]` to `List<TransTripLeg>` instead of `DataTable`

```
var collection = (List<TransTripLeg>)Session["TripRecords"];
var legs = collection.Where(c => c.LegID == sLegID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this symbol just works for me(')
this works fine for me

```
DataRow[] dr = allleaveDt.Select("EmployeeId=" + empId);
```